# How to add Redux Provider as a Storybook (v6) decorator AND use Redux inside of the next decorator?

Tags: redux, react-redux, storybook

I have a global decorator inside `preview.js`

```
const appStore = init();

export const AllProviders = (Story) => (
  <Provider store={appStore}>
    <Story />
  </Provider>
);

export const decorators = [AllProviders];
```

I can see through the Redux dev tools that my store got initialized, but, when I go to my story and do:

```
const GetTheme = (Story) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  (...)

  return (
    <Story />
  );
};

addDecorator(GetTheme);

StyleguideStory('Styleguide');
```

I get an error "could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a < Provider >"

Considering that Global Decorators are rendered first as per [this](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/decorators#decorator-inheritance), and I already have a Provider being added as the first (and only) global decorator, I would expect the next rendered decorator to be able to access the store, am I doing something wrong?

I also tried adding `GetTheme` as the next "globalDecorator" in the array, but for some reason the store is NEVER initialized even though it is the first thing I do through decorators...